How to solve commons-io dependency clash between poi-ooxml & jersery-server?
In one our projects, we use the following packages: jersey-server (2.28) & poi-ooxml(5.2.5). Both these packages have commons-io as sub-dependencies.
While poi-ooxml uses 2.15 version of commons-io, jersey uses 2.11 version, irrespective if we upgrade the jersey to its latest release (https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/blob/3.1.8/tools/jersey-release-notes-maven-plugin/pom.xml#L77).
When we run the project, we get the following error:
<[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread:

'1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <> <[severity-value: 8] [rid: 0] [partition-id: 0] [partition-name: DOMAIN] > <BEA-101017> <[ServletContext@264727129 [app:abc

module:abc.war path:null spec-version: 3.1]] Root cause of ServletException. org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:

org.apache.commons.io.output.UnsynchronizedByteArrayOutputStream.builder()Lorg/apache/commons/io/output/UnsynchronizedByteArrayOutputStreamSBuilder

We have explicitly included commons-io 2.15.1 dependency in Pom.xml so that the project uses this version and ignores the others.
My first impression is that there's a dependency clash for commons-io. Since I am pretty new with Java & inexperienced with it, I would like to know if there's a way to solve this dependency clash.
Edit 1: pom.xml
<dependencies>
<dependency>
<groupId>junit</groupId>
<artifactId>junit</artifactId>
<version>4.12</version>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
<artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
<version>2.28</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
<artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
<version>2.28</version> 
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
<version>1.9.14.jdk17-redhat-00001</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupid> org.apache.commons </groupid>
<artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
<version>4.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
<artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
<version>2.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.jvnet.staxex</groupId>
<artifactId>stax-ex</artifactId>
<version>1.7.7</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
<artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
<version>4.1.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
<artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
<version>5.0.3</version> <!--3.1.0->
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-xc</artifactId>
<version>1.9.14.jdk17-redhat-00001</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>cglib</groupId>
<artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
<version>3.2.6</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
<artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
<version>5.2.5</version> 
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
<version>4.1</version>
</dependency>

<!dependency>
<groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
<artifactId>jersey-media-json</artifactId>
<version>2.0-m05-1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
<version>1.9.14.jdk17-redhat-00001</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
<version>1.9.14.jdk17-redhat-00001</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>clojure-interop</groupId>
<artifactId>javax.net</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
<artifactId>activation</artifactId>
<version>2.1.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId> <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
<version>9.6</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.daisy.pipeline</groupId> <artifactId>common-stax</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.daisy.pipeline</groupId>
<artifactId>common-stax</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.daisy.pipeline</groupId>
<artifactId>common-utils</artifactId>
<<version>6.0.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
<version>1.17.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
<version>2.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>com.github.virtuald</groupId>
<artifactId>curvesapi</artifactId>
<version>1.08</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.daisy.pipeline</groupId> <artifactId>framework-core</artifactId>
<version>8.0.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
<artifactId>guava</artifactId>
<version>33.2.1-jre</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>commons-io</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
<version>2.15.1</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>


Please include pom.xml

@AnishB. It is a very long fine and I can't add it completely here. Do you need any explicit part of it?

When you start your project what commons-io dependencies are on the classpath and in which order? Also maven has a feature called effective pom  which may help you to understand what the actual maven configuration is that will be used in a maven module.

@some_programmer some explicit part only where you have added jersey and common-io

Please post a reduced version of your pom.xml, where you have verified that it still shows the problem.

Please post also more lines of the stack trace, so that it is possible to figure out which class is calling the non-existent method.

@AnishB.  added the reduced version of pom.xml

what if you don't  explicitly included commons-io 2.15.1 dependency in Pom.xml ? Or exclude it from poi-xml dependency.

@Mr_Thorynque It doesn't work. We tried it

I don't know why 2.15.1 was not compatible with 2.11 version. https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/changes-report.html#a2.15.1

Which application server do you use ? Maybe you need to upgrade it.

@Mr_Thorynque Linux server and it’s already upgraded to RHEL 9.4v

With the error message I could think that IS a weblogic app serveur, maybe you can try to upgrade this packagé. You can try to run on tomcat on a local machine.

run in your project mvn dependency:tree and post the relevant portions with the dependencies you think are clashing.

I tried testing. The commons-io-2.11 is only coming from commons-fileupload 1.5. There is no such dependency for commons-fileupload 2.0. Jersey 3.x is not even bringing the common-io.2.11. Please post the full pom.xml

If you are using weblogic as an Application Server, there may be some conflicts between your application and the AS libraries (I once experienced that issue...); you can try adding in the weblogic.xml metadata this tag: <prefer-application-packages><package-name>org.apache.commons.*</package-name><package-name>org.glassfish.jersey.*</package-name></prefer-application-packages> and check if the error changes.

Since the issue shows up durind war deployment, I suspect, as I already wrote in the comments, that is a classpath problem, that weblogic seems to suffer commonly. I think that there is this clash between the AS version of commons-io and the one that is deployed in your application.
You can address this situations, writing a weblogic.xml file that has to be put in the same directory of web.xml, that contains the following:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<wls:weblogic-web-app
    xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_0.xsd
http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app
http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.4/weblogic-web-app.xsd">

    <wls:container-descriptor>
        <wls:prefer-application-packages>
            <wls:package-name>org.apache.commons.*</wls:package-name>
        </wls:prefer-application-packages>
    </wls:container-descriptor>
</wls:weblogic-web-app>

As explained here (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e21049/weblogic_xml.htm#WBAPP571) there are a number of tags that may be set to force weblogic to use application classes / resources / packages over the AS ones.
I suggest you to try this approach to check if forcing this classpath modification leads to changes in the application deployment; maybe you will have to add some other packages in the above list.

You can use exclusions tag to exclude transitive dependency
<dependency>
  <groupId>sample.ProjectA</groupId>
  <artifactId>Project-A</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>  <!-- declare the exclusion here -->
      <groupId>sample.ProjectB</groupId>
      <artifactId>Project-B</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions> 
</dependency>

